# HOWTO Change Drive Letter of DVD Drive on Windows Server 2008 Server Core

Tags: configuration, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I am configuring an HP Proliant DL580 G5 Server to run Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Server Core with Hyper-V.

The storage configuration is as follows

RAID1 2x36GB 
Two RAID5 arrays - RAID0 and RAID1 - 4x300GB

After installation the drive letters assigned to the disks were C: (system), D: (RAID0), E: (RAID1), F: (SWAP) and G: for the DVD drive.  Using DISKPART.EXE, I changed the drive letter assignments to C: (system), E: (RAID0), F: (RAID1), X: (SWAP) respectively.

How do I change the DVD drive from G: to D:?

Any help greatly appreciated.

James

Answer (score 1):

Do you get an error message when you try using Diskpart to change the DVD drive's letter too? There shouldn't be anything stopping this.

Comment: +1; I've done this successfully using Diskpart many times in the past.